# Convert lift-json JValue into MongoDBObject using Casbah?

Tags: mongodb, casbah, lift-json

I'm trying to convert a parsed JSON document in a lift-json's JValue into a Casbah MongoDBObject - is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the lift-json into a Map[String, Any] and then use the implicit asDBObject method on Map:

```
val record = record.values.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
record.asDBObject
```

Comment: This works, but lift-json uses `BigInt` for it's `JInt` implementation which is not compatible with mongodb. Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

Then there is also the [`net.liftweb.mongodb.JObjectParser`](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/liftweb-2.4/#net.liftweb.mongodb.JObjectParser%24) with its `parse` method. The Casbah implicit will convert `DBObject` into `MongoDBObject`.